# Using SQLite-Net Extensions in winRT

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, nuget, relationships

**I would like to use the SQLite-Net Extensions library in my winRT project.**
https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions

To support sqlite in my Windows 8.1 App I've currently installed **SQLite for Windows Runtime** (Windows 8.1) as VS Extension and **sqlite-net** via NuGet.

- Extension: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a
- sqlite: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net

**To get it working I tried to download the source and build it with the sqlite libs we can use for winRT**. In order to add a reference to SQLite for Windows Runtime I need to change the target to Windows 8.1 only. Doing that will **result in many errors like:** "The name 'BindingsFlags' does not exist in the current context" "Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'"
I've also tried to link the SQLite-Net-PCL directly from my project but in the end it's the same situation.

I really need to add relationships to my sqlite database and would be very very thankful for every help I can get!

Attached you can find a screenshot of my VS2013 where I've changed the references of SQLiteNetExtensions to use the required winRT libraries.

Many many thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

[image]

Comment: If suggested answer helped you fix the problem please mark it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following steps work for me without the need to download the source and possible compilation error:

(I have the following assumptions: I only target Windows 8.1 [As of yours] and I use Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 3)

1. In Visual Studio go to Tools-Extensions & updates-online section and look for sqlite. This package will contain
   required SQLite Binaries.
2. Add a Reference to SQLite for Windows Run-time in your project Reference
3. Add a Reference to Microsoft Visual C++ Run-time package
4. In Nuget package manager console run "Install-package sqlite-net"
5. In Nuget package manager console run "Install-Package SQLiteNetExtensions"

Now you will have a project which Targets Windows  8.1 and also has reference to both SQLiteNetExtensions. Above steps was originally recommended in : [Using SQLite in a Windows Store App](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Using-SQLite-in-a-Windows-c16aea77)

Below is the screenshot of the SQLiteDemo project references downloaded from the link I mentioned earlier which also has reference to **SQLiteNetExtensions** :

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this does work when following exactly this steps to install de libs in the correct order.
Sorry for my absence the last weeks and thus the late vote.